# Having an Ajax Save button and save in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database

I'm currently doing a form whereby customers will have to do the survey form, I'll have a AJAX "Save" button to allow me to save the data into database when the customers did not managed to finish the form itself and then when the customers login again, the form which they did halfway will pop out again and ask them to continue finish the survey form.

Is it possible where AJAX/javascript/jQuery can work with php codes in it (because of the insert query)?

Not very sure with AJAX and all so Thanks for helping!

This is for the "Save" button.

```
<input type="button" onClick="save();" value="Save">
```

This is the insert query whereby it will be inserted in database.

```
    <?php
        include("dbFunctions.php");


        $idQuery = "SELECT id,question,input FROM db_ExtApp1.scFormLayout WHERE surveyID ='$lastID'";
$idResult = sqlsrv_query($conn, $idQuery);

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($idResult)) {
    $fcID = $row['id'];
    $question = $row['question'];
    $surveyTitle = $_SESSION['surveyTitle'];
    $input = $row['input'];

    if (isset($_POST['qns' . $fcID])) {
    $answer = implode(",", $_POST['qns' . $fcID]);
    $newAns = str_replace($singleQuote,$changeQuote,$answer);
    } else {
        $newAns = '';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['others'.$fcID])) {
    $others = $_POST['others' . $fcID];
    $newOthers = str_replace($singleQuote,$changeQuote,$others);
    }else {
        $newOthers = 'N.A.';
    }

$connectionInfo['ConnectionPooling']=0; // this creates a new connection on the next line...
$newconn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo); 
if ($input != 'Normal text line, no input required*') {
    $query = "INSERT INTO db_ExtApp1.scFormResult(surveyID, answer, others, title, question, name)
VALUES ('$lastID','$newAns','$newOthers', '$surveyTitle','$question', '$name')";

    $status = sqlsrv_query($newconn, $query);
} }
    if ($status === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    } 
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Comment: where is ajax ? and its possible that you can make ajax request with php ... but php is server side

Comment: I have no idea how to start off writing the codes for ajax because I'm not familiar with it. That's why I'm currently asking for help, at least for guidances so I can write out the codes or try it out...

Comment: you can see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5004233/1723893) its jquery with ajax ... see this it will help you to make ajax request and you can get data from ajax request

Comment: In a nutshell, you use ajax to send the contents of the form to the server, where you use php to take that information and do the proper database queries. And good thing, too, because queries in your javascript would be a security nightmare.

Comment: the ajax call needs to hit a PHP service, if this is doing something like adding to the database, deleting from the database you should likely add a OAuth security layer... For this look at jQuery ajax examples and PHP RESTful services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery $.ajax() to send data from client side to PHP. (eg)

```
$.ajax({
url : 'path/to/php/page',
data : { id : '1', name : 'name' },
dataType : 'JSON',
type : 'POST',
cache: false,
success : function(succ) {
alert(succ);
},
error : function(err) {
alert(err);
}
});
```

Then in PHP page, use $_POST[] to capture data and insert it into database.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Make sure you escape the values and make it safe for sql insert.